# Conditionally render JSX on specific routes

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, react-router, styled-components

I built a React Component Layout for SplitScreen pages (the bottom layout design on the screen shot).

[image]

The problem is that the LoginPage layout (the top layout design on the screen shot) I won't need the backArrowIcon at to top, as you can better see on the second screen shot.

[image]

I also would have to change the Left<->Right split display on the screen on the LoginPage container.

Anyone has a clue of what can I do to solve my two problems?

Here's also my SplitScreen Component code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, useHistory, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import logoImg from '../../assets/images/logo.svg';
import backIcon from '../../assets/images/icons/back.svg';

import './styles.css';

function SplitScreen(props: { children: React.ReactNode; }) {
  return (
    <section className="split-page-container">
      <div className="right-side">
        <Link
          className="back-arrow"                 // Here's the backArrowIcon
          to="/">
          <img src={backIcon} alt="Voltar" />
        </Link>
        <div className="proffy">
          <div className="proffy-fundo">
            <img src={logoImg} alt="Proffy Logo" />
            <h2>Sua plataforma de <br /> estudos online.</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="left-side">
        <div className="content-box">
          {props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default SplitScreen;
```

and here's my CSS:

```
.split-page-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;

  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.left-side, .right-side {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.left-side {
  background: var(--color-background);
}

.right-side {
  background: var(--color-primary);
}

.content-box {
  padding: 5.6rem 3.2rem;
}

.back-arrow {
  align-self: flex-start;
  padding: 1.2rem 1.8rem;
  height: 0;
  color: var(--color-text-in-primary);
}

.right-side a {
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.right-side a:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.proffy {
  height: 37.9rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.proffy-fundo {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 23.8rem;
  height: 26.6rem;
  background-image: url('../../assets/images/success-background.svg');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}

.proffy-fundo img {
  width: 16rem;
}

.proffy-fundo h2 {
  width: 16rem;
  
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  margin-top: 0.8rem;

  color: var(--color-text-in-primary);
}

@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  .split-page-container {
    flex-flow: row-reverse nowrap;       // How can I delete this .split-page-container styling on
  }                                      // my LoginPage container?

  .back-arrow {
    color: var(--color-primary-darker);
    transform: translate(-39vw, -23vh);
  }

  .right-side a {
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
  }
  
  .right-side a:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }

  .proffy-fundo {
    width: 40rem;
    height: 58.4rem;
  }

  .proffy-fundo img {
    width: 33.4rem;
  }

  .proffy-fundo h2 {
    width: 33.4rem;

    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    line-height: 3.4rem;
    margin-top: 0.8rem;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the location pathname and check if on your login route.

[useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation)

If not on your login route then conditionally render the back button.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, useLocation, useHistory, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import logoImg from '../../assets/images/logo.svg';
import backIcon from '../../assets/images/icons/back.svg';

import './styles.css';

function SplitScreen(props: { children: React.ReactNode; }) {
  const { pathname } = useLoction();

  const showBack = !pathname.startsWith("/login");

  return (
    <section className="split-page-container">
      <div className="right-side">
        {showBack && (
          <Link
            className="back-arrow"
            to="/">
            <img src={backIcon} alt="Voltar" />
          </Link>
        )}
        <div className="proffy">
          <div className="proffy-fundo">
            <img src={logoImg} alt="Proffy Logo" />
            <h2>Sua plataforma de <br /> estudos online.</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="left-side">
        <div className="content-box">
          {props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

If you simply want to swap the left and right sides you can swap the classnames.

```
function SplitScreen(props: { children: React.ReactNode; }) {
  const { pathname } = useLoction();

  const showBack = !pathname.startsWith("/login");

  return (
    <section className="split-page-container">
      <div className="left-side"> // <-- now the left side
        {showBack && (
          <Link
            className="back-arrow"
            to="/">
            <img src={backIcon} alt="Voltar" />
          </Link>
        )}
        <div className="proffy">
          <div className="proffy-fundo">
            <img src={logoImg} alt="Proffy Logo" />
            <h2>Sua plataforma de <br /> estudos online.</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="right-side"> // <-- now the right side
        <div className="content-box">
          {props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. Drew! But I only want to swap the screen sides on my login page, so how thid would not affect my other pages?

Comment: I just solved the issue of flippin the page sides on my Login Page doing:
let splitPageClassName = "split-page-container";
  if (!notLoginPath) {
    splitPageClassName = "login-split-page-container";
  }
and saying <span className={splitPageClassName}>...</span>

and then adding .login-split-page-container to my CSS

Thank you man! Couldn't make it without your support!

Comment: @FernandoRodriguesCoelho Sorry I wasn't able to respond more quickly, but yeah, I missed the part that this is a generic page container versus an instance of specific page. I'd expose out a boolean prop to swap panels, i.e. `swapPanels` and simply set the classnames, i.e. `className={swapPanels ? "left-side" : "right-side"}` for the first section and `className={swapPanels ? "right-side" : "left-side"}` for the second section. I'd probably also go ahead and show/hide the back button based on a prop as well. This helps keep a visual UI component decoupled from any specific use-case.

Comment: thank you very much man, you really helped me on that!

Comment: @FernandoRodriguesCoelho Welcome. Glad to help out.